# Regex to match certain filename and extensions

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex that matches all file names but `pom` and `beans`, and the extensions could be only `java`, `properties` or `xml`.

For file name I used 
`^(?!beans$|pom$)\S*`

For extension I used `java|properties|xml`

They both work when tested independently on regex101, but when I try to add them together it won't work

I've tried

`(^(?!beans$|pom$)\S*)\.(java|properties|xml)`

But it doesn't work

Comment: So you want to match anything with those extensions except if the filename is `pom.java` (or any of the other extensions, or `beans`)? Or do you want to ensure the filename doesn't include `pom` or `beans` such that you also don't match something like `xpomx.java`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(?!pom|beans)([a-z0-9]+)\.(java|properties|xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match name.extension just might use this regex:

[`^(?!beans|pom)\w+\.(?:java|properties|xml)$`](https://regex101.com/r/O0qf67/1)

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- A negative lookahead that asserts not beginning with beans or pom `(?!beans|pom)`
- a word character one or more times `\w+`
- until you encounter a dot `.`
- a non capturing group that checks for java or properties or xml `(?:java|properties|xml)`
- at the end of the line `$`

You could use `\S+` instead of `\w+` but that would also match:

```
temp.test.properties
test.beans.properties
```

[`^(?!beans|pom)\S+\.(?:java|properties|xml)$`](https://regex101.com/r/f68xe0/1/)